# How to remove Thousand 'k' suffix from Amcharts-Stockchart

Tags: javascript, css, amcharts

I have created a `Stockchart` using Amcharts available in https://codepen.io/Volabos/pen/PyzmYd

Where everything looks good, I however want to get rid of the `Thousand-k suffix` from `Y-axis lables` as well as from `Baloon`, instead I desire to have **Thousand seperator + rounded value upto 2**.

Is there any possibility to achieve such?

Besides, I also want to **set various `CSS` properties of the `div class = 'Right'` dynamically** based on the value of `"value2"` e.g. if its *value is greater than 500 then Font-color would be green otherwise red*.

Any pointer would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the y-axis, change `usePrefixes` in your `panelSettings` to false:

```
"panelsSettings": {
  "usePrefixes": false
},
```

For the balloon, implement [balloonFunction](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/StockGraph#balloonFunction) to customize the formatting:

```
stockGraphs: [{
  "id": "g1",
  ...
  "balloonFunction": function(graphDataItem, graph) {
    var value = graphDataItem.values.value;
    return "<div>Value<br/>" + Math.round(value).toLocaleString('en-us'); + "</div>";
  }
}]
```

[Updated pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jeMxMZ)

**EDIT**

Here is the [updated pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PyGBLZ) to include dynamic balloon colors based on `value2`. The new balloonFunction looks like this:

```
function(graphDataItem, graph) {
  var value = graphDataItem.values.value;
  var value2 = graphDataItem.dataContext.rawData[0].value2;
  return "<div style='color:" + (value2 > 500 ? 'green' : 'red') + "'>Value<br/>" + 
    Math.round(value).toLocaleString('en-us'); +
    "</div>";
}
```

You can clean this up with string interpolation and CSS classes as well, but this is basically the technique.

Comment: Thanks Danny, this is excellent. Any idea how to style Balloon text for 'value1' based on the value of 'value2' series?

Comment: Updated my answer, be sure to hit that checkmark if it helps!